# Change one property in core data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

How quickly in each of them change one property? if each individually receive from core data and change one property, for 10,000 objects, for example, it will last 40 seconds and it's a long. What if the solution to this problem?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You're individually fetching 10,000 objects, changing a single attribute on each one and then saving again? Are you saving each individually?

Comment: save after all operations

Comment: @Evgeniy: I think the problem is the large number of fetch requests, for each currency and rate separately. - Why have you removed your code again?

Answer (score 0):

Change all of the items properties, and only in the end do the save operation- one save operation for all the entities.

Most of the time is actually the saving to the disk, not changing the property.

Comment: I do so, but it takes about 1 minute. if I had done with queries in sqlite, for example, it would take a few seconds. sense then to core data?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with CoreData. Try to go deeper with that, maybe using Instruments tools to understand which line takes most of the time. You can also use NSLog to measure times.
Maybe it's 'currencyWithId', 'rateWithDate:date' or some other heavy methods.